# Find Phone Number functionality?

Tags: query

I am achieving search Phone functionality, working fine for simple number formats but not for (91)-33333333333 kind of number formats

Comment: Hi vikas, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. What's your question exactly? Are you writing a search page? Can you **[edit]** your post to include relevant code, if any?

Answer (score 3):

Searching for Phone fields in Salesforce is a little awkward. When using the UI if your User Locale is set to English (United States) or English (Canada). [Salesforce does following things by the JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_about.htm).

> 1. If telephone number contains 9 digits -
>      It will be Saved as it is in Salesforce - Ex: 949243871
> 2. If telephone number contains 10 digit -
>      If the phone number starts with 1 it will be saved as is without any formatting.
>      If starts with any other digit other than 1, it will be Saved as : (***) ***-****
> 3. If telephone number contains 11 digits there are 2 cases
>
> If 11 digit number starts with 1 it will automatically convert in the 10 digit format by removing the 1 in the number 
>               Ex: If the number is like this => 12365478963 
>                     It will be saved as in Salesforce => (236) 547-8963 
>   Note: It removes the 1 and formats the other numbers as like 10 Digit Number.
>
> If 11 digits but not starting with the 1 then it will stored as it is in the Salesforce. 
>                 Ex: If the number is like this => 23654789631
>                     It will be saved as in Salesforce => 23654789631

Note: This does not apply to Phone numbers of records created via API, example Web-to-Lead.

This can cause inconsistent formatting in the Database and when searching via SOQL your query has to match EXACTLY.  So if in the Database a record Phone number is stored as `(330) 555-1234` and your SOQL looks like

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Phone = '3305551234'
```

Then no records will be returned.

---

If all you need to do is search Phone numbers you may want to consider [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_about.htm).  SOSL will disregard formats. The thing you will need to take into account is that it will search all fields with the `Phone` Data Type.  So if your Lead record has both `Phone` and `MobilePhone` populated a SOSL search will match both. SOSL would look something like this.

```
FIND {3305551234} IN PHONE FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Id, Name, Phone, MobilePhone)
```

Also note that SOSL returns a List of a List of sObject (because it can return multiple sObjects).